# postgres client editing a query

Tags: postgresql-9.2

When I'm constructing a query in postgres I don't want the query on a single line. I want to have some structure so after each part of the query I hit the return key. It results in a secondary prompt after which one can continue typing.
Once I am finished the query is terminated with a ; and pressing enter results in executing the query. So far so good.

But if I made a mistake and want to go to the previous line I can't do that.

Pressing the arrow-up key results in selecting the previously executed query. 
Continuously pressing the arrow-left key results in going to the beginning of the current line.

What am I doing wrong? I use PostgreSQL 9.2.23.

Comment: after you hit `;` enter, the query gets to history. you can edit last query with your vafourite editor, eg vi, to do it, enter `\e` and hit enter

Comment: That's what I do now: Execute the query with an error, popup the query from the historylist , correct the error and execute it. But it must be possible to make corrections beforehand.  Especially if it's a time consuming query.

Comment: then dont hit the enter. use uparrow to pickup the query you change (if you want) and use back forward to place cursor

Comment: You can use a GUI client: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools